# lowercase to all files in a directory expecting to undo it at some point

Tags: bash, rename

Okay, so I want to batch rename files (and files within subdirectories) in a directory to lowercase, but I also want to undo that at some point. Should I store their real names somewhere so I can go back to the original structure once I am done?

Can this be done in bash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes, quite straightforward

```
for f in *; do
    mv "$f" "${f,,}"
    printf "mv %q %q\n" "${f,,}" "$f" >> restore.sh
done
```

run `bash restore.sh` to restore the former file names.

---

Recursive: trickier than first appears: I ended up processing the files and directories separately, only renaming the base part of the path.

```
declare -A restore=([f]=restore_file.sh [d]=restore_dir.sh)
for type in f d; do
    find . -type $type -print0 | while IFS= read -rd '' path; do
        base=$(basename "$path")
        lower="$(dirname "$path")/${base,,}"
        mv "$path" "$lower"
        printf "mv %q %q\n" "$lower" "$path" >> "${restore[$type]}"
    done
done
```

To restore:

```
bash restore_dir.sh
bash restore_file.sh
```

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect. But is there a way to make it recursive? That is to apply it to subdirectories as well?

Comment: Are spaces in filenames going to mess things up in the reversal script?

Comment: Spaces will not be a problem: bash's `printf %q` will properly escape them.

Comment: the recursive version fails at restoring. This is because it stores all subdirectories as lowercase, but once the foldername is restored the mv commands fail because they can't find the lower-case foldername.

Comment: This is awesome.  If only I could up-vote more than once.

Answer (score 1):

The rename is simple enough with a little transform with `rename`. The following is inert (remove the -n flag to make it do things) and it will tell you what it' doing:

```
rename 'tr/A-Z/a-z/' -vn *
```

However, if you want to build that into a reversible script, you have to do a bit more:

```
rename 'tr/A-Z/a-z/' -vn * | sed 's/ renamed as /#/' | awk -F'#' '{print "mv '\''" $2 "'\'' '\''" $1 "'\''"}' > reverse.sh
```

---

If you need to change the list of files going into this (eg recursive), you can either pipe names into rename:

```
find | rename ...
```

Or use some Bash options for globbing recursively:

```
shopt -s globstar
rename ... ** *
```

Comment: That's great but I think the problem is that it renames the folder before renaming its content because i keep getting "no such files or directory" for all files in the subdirectories. The subdirectories themselves change names, but the content doesn't

Comment: One potential risk with your awk script: filenames may contain single quotes.

Comment: @CarrKnight if using `find`, use the `-depth` option.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=$'\n'
WORKING_PATH=$(pwd $1)

RESTORE_FILENAME="$WORKING_PATH/restore_case.sh"

echo "#!/bin/bash" > "$RESTORE_FILENAME"
chmod a+x "$RESTORE_FILENAME"


for FILEPATH in $(find . -type f)
do
    FILENAME="${FILEPATH##*/}"
    LOWER_FILE="${FILEPATH::-${#FILENAME}}${FILENAME,,}"

    if [ "$LOWER_FILE" != "$FILEPATH" ]; then
        echo moving "$FILEPATH" to "$LOWER_FILE"
        echo mv \""$LOWER_FILE"\" \""$FILEPATH"\" >> "$RESTORE_FILENAME"_files
        mv "$FILEPATH" "$LOWER_FILE"
    fi
done

touch "$RESTORE_FILENAME"_dirs

for DIRPATH in $(find . -type d -printf "%d%p\n"|sort -nr)
do
    DIRPATH=${DIRPATH:1}
    DIRNAME="${DIRPATH##*/}"
    LOWER_DIRPATH="${DIRPATH::-${#DIRNAME}}${DIRNAME,,}"
    if [ "$LOWER_DIRPATH" != "$DIRPATH" ]; then
        echo moving "$DIRPATH" to "$LOWER_DIRPATH"
        echo -e "mv \""$LOWER_DIRPATH"\" \""$DIRPATH"\"\n$(cat "$RESTORE_FILENAME"_dirs)" > "$RESTORE_FILENAME"_dirs
        mv "$DIRPATH" "$LOWER_DIRPATH"
    fi
done

cat "$RESTORE_FILENAME"_dirs "$RESTORE_FILENAME"_files >> "$RESTORE_FILENAME"
rm "$RESTORE_FILENAME"_dirs "$RESTORE_FILENAME"_files

echo rm '$0' >> "$RESTORE_FILENAME"
```

longer, a bit dirty, but more precise, also does not do unnecessary mv

Comment: You should use `printf "%q"` like the accepted answer. `echo "mv \"...."` breaks easily.

Comment: Parsing the output of `IFS=$'\n'; find` is vulnerable to filenames that contain newlines. It might be better to use `find . -type f -print0 | while read -d '' FILEPATH ...` or `shopt -s globstar; for FILEPATH in **/* ...`.

Comment: yes, implementation is a bit dirty, but logic is much more precise (which is important for me) also this level  of "vulnerability" is suffice for me., i have no time to dig deep into bash scripting now, just done required task for me, and think someone may find it useful (accepted answer does not fit in my case)